# Multiple jQuery .on() events not working xBrowser (dependent on order)

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript

I'm using the "DOMMouseScroll" event in place of mousewheel in order to support Firefox. I'm not sure why I'm getting the following behavior:

The following will allow DOMMouseScroll to work in Firefox, but my scroll or mousewheel events won't fire.

```
$contents.on 'scroll, mousewheel, DOMMouseScroll', @handleScroll
```

But when I separate out the bindings, everything works fine in Chrome and Firefox.

```
$contents.on 'scroll, mousewheel', @handleScroll
$contents.on 'DOMMouseScroll', @handleScroll
```

If I reorder to the following, I get chrome to work again, but not firefox:

```
$contents.on 'scroll, DOMMouseScroll, mousewheel', @handleScroll
```

So obviously the order matters, where mousewheel is the last binding so it works over DDOMMouseScroll, and separating them out is the solution. I would just like to know why.

When I look at [the jQuery source for .on()](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.fn.on) I see:

```
function (types, selector, data, fn, one) {
    var type, origFn;

    if (typeof types === "object") {
        if (typeof selector !== "string") {
            data = data || selector;
            selector = undefined;
        }
        for (type in types) {
            this.on(type, selector, data, types[type], one);
        }
        return this;
    }
```

Shouldn't the type-in-types loop provide the same effect as creating separate individual bindings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not have commas in `on` method:

```
$contents.on 'scroll mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', @handleScroll
```

In your case jQuery was listening for events like `scroll,` or `DOMMouseScroll,`.

jQuery Docs: https://api.jquery.com/on/